# Example of a locally finite refinement of a family

Tags: general-topology, paracompactness

Consider $C$ is the open cover { $(-n,n): n$$\in$ lN}.
I would like to cconstruct a locally refinement of $C$.
What I considered was $C'$={ $(n,n+2): n$$\in$ lN}. This covers the real line, is locally finite and every $(n,n+2)$ is in $(-n-3,n+3)$ $\in C$, so it is a refinement.

I just wanted to know if what I did is correct. Thank you in advance!

Comment: $C'$ does not cover the real line.  Take $C'=\{ (n,n+2): n \in \mathbb Z\}$

Comment: Oh yes! I meant that, but got distracted. But if I do that, then this is correct, righ?